Angular material: not possible to change the matDateLocale in a datePicker using dateAdapter
I have an Angular 18 (standalone) project where I use DatePicker.
I need to change the language dinamically. For this I am using a service where I inject a DateAdapter, something like this:
export class MyService {
  #dateAdapter = inject(DateAdapter);
  ...
  set locale(locale: 'en' | 'de') {
    this.locale = locale;
    console.log('Before: ' + this.#dateAdapter);
    this.#dateAdapter.setLocale(this.locale);
    console.log('After: ' + this.#dateAdapter);
  }
  ...
}

After starting the service I change the locale to german and the I see in the logs:
Before: _NativeDateAdapter {... _matDateLocale: 'en-US', locale: 'en-US'}
After:  _NativeDateAdapter {... _matDateLocale: 'en-US', locale: 'de'}

The _matDateLocale (used by the DatePicker) remains in English! The calendar is displayed with English labels.
How can I change this internal matDateLocale too?
I have tried to inject in the service LOCALE_ID and MAT_DATE_LOCALE as well, but nothing changes:
  set locale(locale: 'en' | 'de') {
    this.locale = locale;
    console.log('Before: ' + this.#dateAdapter);
    this.#dateAdapter.setLocale(this.locale);
    this.#localeId = this.locale
    this.#matDateLocale = this.locale
    console.log('After: ' + this.#dateAdapter);
  }

My app.config is like this:
  providers: [
    ...,
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: NativeDateAdapter
    },

I have also tried:
  providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en'},
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: NativeDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE],
    },

In this case matDateLocale remains always 'en'.
I have also tried with registerLocaleData(localeDE) to no avail.
It is not possible for me to change the internal matDateLocale, the start value does not change.
This is driving me crazy.  I have followed many different examples found here without success.

which adapter are using for datepicker

Interestingly, setting the locale via LOCALE_ID seems to work even with the native date adapter, while setting it dynamically is not possible.

As per the Docs, there is only support for english locale - Choosing a date implementation and date format settings - Angular Material Docs

provideNativeDateAdapter or MatNativeDateModule
Supported locales -    en-US


Instead go for MatDateFnsModule or MatLuxonDateModule or MatMomentDateModule, which supports multiple locales.
Working Demo for reference

There is indeed support for german, I can see it if I set the provider so:
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de'}
But then, the labels are always in german, it is not possible to set it dynamically to english (with dateAdapter.setLocale)

@JaimeOcampo if you use the other adapters it is possible.
